# In a least squares fit, is the resulting error in the fit parameters considered statistical/random error or systematic error?

Tags: measurements, error-analysis, statistics, data-analysis

In a least squares fit, if there is no error estimate on the input data points, is the resulting error in the fit parameters $\sigma_y$ (which is calculated from residuals) considered statistical/random error or systematic error? Or does it depend on the details of the experiment?

$$\sigma_y^2=\frac{1}{N-n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(y_i-y(x_i, a_0, b_0, c_0, ...))^2$$

Comment: Would [statistics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Your formula is unclear.  Is $\sigma_y$ the estimator of a parameter?  Or is it the error on the parameters as you write?  To me it looks like what you are minimizing, ie the least square.

Answer (score 1):

From the knowledge I have from a few courses I have had, the type of error is determined by the experiment itself. Let me explain myself shortly.

A **systematic error** remains constant in repeated measurements under fixed operating conditions.

When repeated measurements are made under fixed operating conditions, **random errors** manifest themselves as scatter of the measured data. It is introduced through the repeatability of the measurement system components, calibration, and measurement procedure and technique etc.

From this, I would say that it depends on both how you took the data and on the nature of your experiment

Answer (score 1):

The concept of systematic error has been abrogated and is no longer used. See the official NIST publication on evaluating and reporting uncertainty:

https://www.nist.gov/pml/nist-technical-note-1297/nist-tn-1297-2-classification-components-uncertainty

Measurement uncertainty is now classified into the components of uncertainty that are evaluated through statistical methods and the components of uncertainty that are evaluated through other methods. The uncertainty estimated through a least squares fit is a statistical component.

Comment: However, according to that page, "an alternative nomenclature that might be used" is a "component of uncertainty arising from a systematic effect," where "a systematic effect is one that gives rise to a possible systematic error in the current measurement process." My reading is that it is not that the concept of systematic error has been deprecated, but rather that people are encouraged to think about the sources of uncertainty for each measurement process, and not make blanket claims like "X is systematic error" *in general*, without referencing a specific measurement.

Comment: Possibly, but in keeping with the overall context of the whole document, I would discourage such usage, because it doesn’t make much sense juxtaposed with the clear designation of the first component of uncertainty as that being evaluated through statistical means. I.e. the natural complement to “statistical” is “non-statistical”, not “systematic”

Answer (score 0):

This is a statistical uncertainty, based on estimating the variance of the parameters in the model. (see, eg, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares#Uncertainty_quantification).

Systematic uncertainty would occur if there were no values of the parameters $a_0, b_0, c_0, \cdots$ such that the model $y(x_i, a_0, b_0, c_0, \cdots)$ matched the true value.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers by @Dale and @god_operator:

Every point here represents a measurement. A *systematic error* would affect every point and this change the slope and/or the offset of the linear fit. However, the spread of the points around the fit line is due to arrors that are not the same (i.e., not *systematic*!) for all the data points - this is statistical error.